# SAS: Convert character date to numeric in yymmdd10. format

Tags: sas

I need to convert SAS character dates without imputing to numeric dates in yymmdd10. format. I tried several formats but it comes out as blank. Is it possible to change character SAS dates to numeric SAS dates?

```
    data check;
     length date $10;
     date="2013-04-17"; output;
     date="2012-11"; output;
     date="2011-12-13"; output;
     date="2015-03-24"; output;
     date="2014"; output; 
   run;
```

Comment: You should include what you've at least attempted to this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand "without imputing" correctly, the answer is "you can't".

SAS numeric dates are the number of days from January 1, 1960, until the date you specify.  This only has meaning for a specific day: "2014-11" (November 2014) doesn't have a specific number of days from January 1, 1960, for example, there's a 30 day span there, and "2014" is even worse.

When you have only part of the date, you can impute the day, month, or year values (1st, 15th, 30th of the month, or a random day, etc.); but without imputing you cannot have a SAS numeric date value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INPUT()` function to convert a string to a number.  SAS stores dates as numbers, so this function can be used for the conversion.

```
data want;
set check;
format date2 date9.;
date2 = input(date,anydtdte10.);
run;
```

Here `anydtdte10.` is an INFORMAT that tells the function how to interpret the string.  It is a generic INFORMAT for most date strings.

Note the `2014` string is not going to work with this.  You can check for a missing value in `date2` and attempt a different conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It does not work perfectly. However, I will use this and try to update where possible.